# How to enable and disable ELMAH in web.config and in code behind?

Tags: elmah

I am using ELMAH for error reporting in my ASP.NET projects.  Everything is working great, except when I debug a project I don't want to send an email report to the allowed users.
How can I accomplish this feat?

Comment: can you please tell us HOW you are sending emails when an error occurs? I'm assuming you're using ELMAH to send emails when an error occurs .. so can you please show us your web.config settings for ELMAH?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have different web.config files for your development and production environments, just disable Elmah in your development web.config. You'll want to comment out (or remove) the Elmah.ErrorLogModule element in the httpModules section.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to disable ELMAH from code-behind. You can, however, use configuration-specific web.config files to turn it off (or just use a different type of logging) in your development environment. See ScottGu's post here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/21/tip-trick-automating-dev-qa-staging-and-production-web-config-settings-with-vs-2005.aspx

Comment: It doen't work to comment ErrorLogModule.
Comment errorLog from elmah section ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/25394016/2152973

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use [ErrorFiltering](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering) to turn off the email logging in the Global.asax. Something like:

```
void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{

#if DEBUG
    e.Dismiss();
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the ErrorMail_Mailing method.  When ELMAH sends the email, it runs this first (when present in global.asax.cs)

```
public void ErrorMail_Mailing(object sender, ErrorMailEventArgs e)
{
#if DEBUG
    e.Mail.To.Clear();
    e.Mail.To.Add("MyAddress@myDomain.com");
    e.Mail.Subject = "Error in Development";
#endif
}
```

The example above can be via the the transformations in web.Debug.config & web.Release.config.  But there is a lot more you can do in this method.  See http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/01/06/customizing-elmah-s-error-emails.aspx