# Stop Elmah logging dynamically in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, error-logging, elmah.mvc

I have implemented Elmah logging error by using [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/858292/exception-logging-in-mvc-using-elmah/) article in one of my applications and it is running fine as expected.

Now as per the requirements I have to stop logging error dynamically that will handle by the user either user will run logging error or not by simply set in web.config.

But I have no idea how to stop it dynamically and I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393171/how-to-stop-elmah-logging) article but I am not able to stop logging errors.

Is anything I am missing or I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the stackoverflow answer you link to, you can comment out the `ErrorLog` element from your `Web.config`. This doesn't disable logging (as suggested by the accepted answer), but switch to using the in-memory logger in ELMAH. This will log all errors in memory, which shouldn't slow down your installation. If you want to remove error logging completely, you can comment out all of the ELMAH-related modules in `Web.config`.

If you want a toggle, I've described this in my [ELMAH Tutorial](https://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/#turningloggingonoff). Create a new app setting:

```
<add key="ELMAH:disable" value="false" />
```

Then add the following code in your `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ELMAH:disable"]))
        e.Dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but removing all the methods from the web.config is a tedious job and reset all again if the user needed. Do we have anything like settings Switch on and off and based on that it will work for memory and db as well?

Comment: There is no switch to enable/disable ELMAH. It can be easily created, though. I've updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Yes exact what I want. I will try and see if it works. Thanks.